# jQuery toggle - Changing from select input to text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, text, toggle

I'm very new to using jQuery and JavaScript but here goes. I am trying to create a toggle function for my website. There is an input to select the name of the event which displays as default as a dropdown list of all the events in the database - but I want there to be an option to change it to manual input and type the name of the event as what ever you want.

I can get this to work fine! However I can't get the link to change the input BACK to a select box to work.

See my code below:

/// jQuery Code ///

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleEventInput() {
       $("#EventNameDropDown")
.replaceWith('<input type="text" size="35" name="boxEvent" class="FieldInput" />');
        $("#EventNameChange")
.replaceWith('<a href="javascript:toggleEventInputBack();"> (Drop Down Input)</a>');
    }

    function toggleEventInputBack() {
       $("#EventNameDropDown")
.replaceWith('TEST');
        $("#EventNameChange")
.replaceWith('<a href="javascript:toggleEventInput();"> (Manual Input)</a>');
    }   
</script>
```

/// HTML Code ///

```
<table>
       <tr>
        <td class="label">Event:</td>
            <td>
                <span id="EventNameDropDown">
                <select name="boxEvent" class="FieldInput" style="width:254px;" />
                <?= $EventNameDropDownList ?>
                </select>
                </span>
                <span id="EventNameChange">
                <a href="javascript:toggleEventInput();"> (Manual Input)</a>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Company:</td>
            <td><input type="text" size="35" name="boxEvent" class="FieldInput" /></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

As said, when you click the original link to '(Manual Input)' it works fine and changes it to a text box. But then when you click the '(Drop Down Input)' link it does nothing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Two things you should correct. The "Company" input element has the same name as the "Event" input. They are both "boxEvent". You also have a "/" at the end of your select tag.

Comment: Yes sorry I realised the "boxEvent" double after I posted this up here. I've corrected that on the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.html()` instead of `.replaceWith()`. The former replaces the contents of the element. The latter replaces the element itself. By using `.replaceWith()` you are replacing the `<span>` that contains the `<select>` too.

Krishna is suggesting that rather than just replace the html for the `<select>`, you first store it in a variable so you can put it back later.

You could store it as data on an element, like this:

```
function toggleEventInput() {
    // Store the html for the <select>.
    $('#EventNameDropDown').data('selectHtml', $('#EventNameDropDown').html());

    $("#EventNameDropDown").html('<input type="text" size="35" name="boxEvent" class="FieldInput" />');
    $("#EventNameChange").html('<a href="javascript:toggleEventInputBack();"> (Drop Down Input)</a>');
}

function toggleEventInputBack() {
    $("#EventNameDropDown").html($('#EventNameDropDown').data('selectHtml'));
    $("#EventNameChange").html('<a href="javascript:toggleEventInput();"> (Manual Input)</a>');

    // Clear the html for the <select>. We will get it again later if we need it.
    $('#EventNameDropDown').data('selectHtml', '');
}
```

Comment: Thank you John S. That worked perfectly!

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. Please click to accept the answer. You could also up-vote Krishna's answer since it was helpful.

Comment: Accepted. Wont let me vote up Krishna's answer as it says I need 15 rep? This is my first time on this site.

Anyway if he's reading this - thank you also! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Its better to add the drop-down list inside a div/span and while clicking the toggle button, store the data inside the div/span to a variable and replace the content with the input box. on next toggle, replace the div/span with that data in the variable. a status variable 0/1 will help to toggle the data..

Comment: Im not sure I understand how to do that. Could you help out a little?

Comment: for instance using a hidden element, like: `<div class="rememberValue" value="True" hidden></div>`